# How to skip header in multi-line records when consuming data from Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to know about how to skip the headers when the spark consume data from kafka.

my kafka topic contains message as follows at a particular time:

```
name,age,year
ton,33,2018
fon,34,2019
```

whenever i consume data from kafka i want to skip the header part.

my spark structured streaming consumer as follows;

```
 val kafkaDatademostr = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","fffff.dl.ggg.com:8023").option("subscribe","dfo").option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_PLAINTEXT").load

 val interval=kafkaDatademostr.select(col("value").cast("string"),col("timestamp")).alias("csv").select("csv.*")
```

Can someone help me how to skip header part while consuming data from kafka ? i am new to spark structured streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` column is the value of a Kafka record and in your case it looks like it is just a multi-line string (with new line characters and the first line what you call a header). Spark does not know it and so you have to parse the records yourself after you pull them from Kafka.

BTW, it is alike in Spark SQL with the Kafka data source. Replace `readStream` with `read` and see yourself.